# $(e.target) is <i></i> and not the containing <div>...</div>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been working on a large script which checks the data-action and now I've implemented a hover to show some icons; like so:

```
<div class="Flag" data-action="mail-flag"><i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

However with this not having plain text within and instead an icon, `if ($(e.target).attr('data-action')) {` does not work as `$(e.target)` is the `<i></i>`.

How can I get `if ($(e.target).attr('data-action')) {` to work on the `<div>...</div>` without adding the `data-action="mail-flag"` to the `<i></i>`?

Comment: `$(e.target).parent().attr('data-action')`

Comment: I thought about this, however what if the child and parent have a `date-action` set which will conflict. I'm not sure how likely this is and I don't think I've done this so far so this _could_ work... The next line in this section after the `if` though is `var action = $(e.target).data('action'),`

Comment: Actually you will want to use `$(e.target).parents(".Flag")` in case you change the structure of the HTML. I do not understand what you mean by a conflicting `data-action` set; the child has no `data-action`.

Comment: This seems to have done the trick. I've added a an if statement to check whether `$(e.target).attr('data-action')` exists to set `action = $(e.target).attr('data-action')`, else `action = $(e.target).parent.attr('data-action')`. If you submit an answer I'll be able to mark this question has answered.

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the element, then its parent. First, check if

```
$(e.target).attr('data-action')
```

exists. If it does not, use

```
$(e.target).parents(".Flag").attr('data-action')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use event delegation to access the attribute value.

```
$('div[data-action]').on('mouseenter', 'i.fa', function(e){
    console.log($(e.delegateTarget).data('action'))
})
```